# I'm new to UV unwrapping. Why are the seams stretched in parts of the anvil I'm making?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have been following a tutorial on how to make an anvil. I'm at the part where I'm supposed to UV Unwrap but came across an issue with parts of the anvil being stretched even after marking the seams and unwrapping. Is it the mesh, should I try to remake the anvil? I'm a beginner at Blender so I have no clue on what to do with this exact problem.

There were a few videos I watched, but none that explained on what to do if I had this specific problem.

[image]

This is where (marked on the images) the unwrapping won't "de-stretch" however much I try to fix it without breaking Blender with stuff I'm not familiar with. I will try to add the file as well if needed.

How can I fix this?

I added in the file here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove all stretching you will need to add more seams for Blender to cut it up and flatten it out.

Some geometry is mathematically impossible to unwrap to 2D without stretching. For example, the following will always have angle stretch

[image]

while adding this seams removes it.

[image]

If there is no stretching in the tutorial video, check again what seams they have - likely you have different geometry.

Comment: This is useful! I still can't wrap my head around this. I will try messing around with it until I can get it right for this type of mesh. I added the file as well, maybe I can be pointed towards a better solution.